# How to extract a part of a decimal in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two columns called **quantity** and **price**. Quantity is **divided** by price. If the result contains **decimal**, I want the number **before** the decimal. Or else, the number as it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
select floor(quantity / price) as output
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting issues?

select cast(quantity / price  as bigint)

By the way, I think you may want this: 
[Hive Data Types Manual](http://%20https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-date)

Answer (score 0):

Also [DIV](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ArithmeticOperators) operator can be used (for integer arguments):

```
 with your_data as (
    select stack(3, 13,2,8,2,233,2) as(quantity,price)
    )

 select quantity div price
   from your_data d 
 ;
```

Result:

```
6
4
116
```